# How can I implement this layout with mui grid system?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, frontend

I don't know how to implement this using the mui grid system

Please someone help me to implement this layout

I tried a lot but could not implement this layout with the mui grid system But again, I could not position the footer and nav. this layour --> [Please look at this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRkuC.png)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77538875/edit) your question to include your attempts and clarify specifics. The current form is broad and lacks code, risking closure. Refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [Homework Guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812) for better structuring. Improved questions have a higher chance of staying open and receiving answers.